# .push doesn't seem to be adding to my array

Tags: javascript, processing, p5.js

I have called the `.push` function, but nothing is being added to my array. Here is my code:

```
function setup() {
  createCanvas(400, 400);
}
let digits = [];
function binaryConverter(num){
  this.num = num;
    for(let i = 0; this.num === 0; i++){
    digits.push(this.num % 2);
    this.num = floor(this.num/=2);
  }
}
function draw() {
  background(220);
  binaryConverter(13);
  print(digits);
}
```

I expected the program to output the digits, but it outputs empty arrays.

Comment: What exactly is your question? Please add more details to your post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second statement in the [for loop](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_loop_for.asp) defines the condition which has to be fulfilled for executing the code block of the loop. The code block of the loop is executed as long as the condition is fullfilled

The initial value of `this.num` is `num` (which is 13 in your case). So the condition `this.num === 0` is never fulfilled and the statements in the code block of the loop are never executed.

Change the condition statement in the for loop:

<s>`for(let i = 0; this.num === 0; i++)`</s>
`for(let i = 0; this.num != 0; i++)`